# NFA on 3 states with equivalent DFA on at least 8 states

Tags: automata, finite-automata

For all NFA $A = (Q, \Sigma, Q_0, \Delta, F)$ such that:

1. $\Sigma = \{0,1\}$
2. $|Q| = 4$

There exists a complete DFA $A' = (Q', \Sigma, q_0, \delta, F')$ such that:

1. $L(A) = L(A')$
2. $|Q'| \leq 15$

How does one go about the proof of such a thing? I think it should be true that if $|Q| = 3$, then $|Q'| \leq 7$, however I am not able to formulate a strong claim. Any help in this matter would yield great fruit.

Comment: Do you know how to determinize an NFA?

Comment: The statement is false. Moore showed that the powerset construction is tight, and his example uses a binary alphabet. See *On the Bounds for State-Set Size in the Proofs of
Equivalence Between Deterministic, Nondeterministic,
and Two-Way Finite Automata* by Frank R. Moore.